# Is there a way to use Twilio python lookup api print output and use the caller name found as variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio api for lookup with python. How can I use the caller-name returned by twilio as a variable to update the phone number owner name field in the database or is there any other way to achieve it?

I tried to use 'stdout' to create an instance of print(phone_number.caller_name)

## twilio lookup codes

```
phone_number = client.lookups.phone_numbers('+1(000) 000-0001').fetch(type='caller-name')

print(phone_number.caller_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'd make a dictionary to save the value corresponding to the `caller_name` key as a variable like so:

`name_dict = phone_number.caller_name
print(name_dict['caller_name'])`

Comment: Thank you so much @lizziepika. I have tried the same logic with print(name_dict('caller_name'))...never worked. Your solution did the job!!

Comment: No problem Curtis! If you could mark it as the answer too that'd be much appreciated haha :')